# httpget + URI + HttpClient bibliotecas descontinuadas. Como actualizar código?

Tags: java, android, api

Preciso de aceder a API [Panoramio](http://www.panoramio.com/api/data/api.html) para ir buscar algumas imagens consoante as coordenadas enviadas.

Contudo estou com problemas para receber o valor JSON.

Depois de várias pesquisas, todas indicam código identico a este, mas as bibliotecas usadas estão descontinuadas. É possivel fazer uma alteração para outra biblioteca qualquer?

Código:

```
    try {
        final URI uri = new URI("http", url, null);
        final HttpGet get = new HttpGet(uri);
        final HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        final HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
        final HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        final String str = Utilities.convertStreamToString(entity.getContent());
        final JSONObject json = new JSONObject(str);
        parse(json);
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
    }
```

A minha tentativa de conversão:

```
     URL urll = new URL(endPoint);
     URLConnection connection = urll.openConnection();    
     InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

     BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

     StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
     String line;

      while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null){

            result.append(line);
      }

      final String str = result.toString();
      final JSONObject json = new JSONObject(str);
```

Alguma ajuda?

Obrigado.

[Código original](https://github.com/google/googletv-android-samples/blob/master/Panoramio/src/com/google/android/panoramio/ImageManager.java)

Comment: Sim, contudo preferia o uso de bibliotecas nativas do Android...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode utilizar a classe [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) em conjunto com uma [técnica estúpida](http://nosymbolfound.blogspot.com.br/2013/01/stupid-scanner-tricks.html) de usar o delimitador `\A` para obter todo o conteúdo de uma entrada de dados.

Das palavras do autor do artigo acima:

> Lembre-se que `Scanner` recebe uma entrada de qualquer classe que implemente `Readable`: `InputStream`, `File`, `Chanel` e assim por diante.
>   (...) Lembre-se também que `\A` corresponde ao início de uma entrada e, uma vez que existe apenas um início em uma entrada, `Scanner` vai buscar todo o fluxo de uma vez.

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;

public final class Test {

    private Test(){}

    public static final String getContentsFromUrl(URL url){
        String contents = "";
        try(Scanner scanner = new Scanner(url.openStream()).useDelimiter("\\A")){
            if(scanner.hasNext())
                contents = scanner.next();
        } catch(IOException ex){
            // seja legal e trate as exceções :)
        }   
        return contents;
    }
}
```

E para usar:

```
String data = Test.getContentsFromUrl(new URL("http://foo.com/json"));
if(!data.isEmpty()){
  // otimitindo try/catch para criar o JSONObject
  JSONObject json = new JSONObject(data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a biblioteca [okhttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) para fazer o download do json, que extremamente fácil sua implementação e muito aplicativos "grandes" usam ela como por exemplo o Spotify e o Duo.

Para adicionar ao seu projeto basta adicionar a seguinte linha nas dependências do seu build.gradle

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
```

segue um exemplo da utilização dela:

```
public String getDadosServer(){
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    String run(String url) throws IOException {
      Request request = new Request.Builder()
          .url(url)
          .build();

      Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
      return response.body().string();
    }
```

Para converter o Json recebido em objeto existem varias bibliotecas como [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) que foi feita pela Google, existe também a [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson), mas ambas envolvem reflection, e no java, mais especificamente no Android, reflection é um recurso extremamente lento.. Então recomendo a [LoganSquare](https://github.com/bluelinelabs/LoganSquare), que gera um código durante a compilação do projeto, otimizando a execução do mesmo.

Para adicionar no seu projeto algumas regras devem ser seguidas:
No seu build.gradle adicione o seguinte:

```
 buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
        }
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt' //este plugin será responsável por gerar o código durante a compilacao

    dependencies {
        apt 'com.bluelinelabs:logansquare-compiler:1.3.6'
        compile 'com.bluelinelabs:logansquare:1.3.6'
    }
```

e no seu projeto você precisa criar uma classe que representa o json recebido para fazer a conversão automatica do JSON para o objeto..

Segue um exemplo...

```
@JsonObject
public class SeuObjeto{

    @JsonField
    public String format;


    @JsonField(name = "_id")
    public int imageId;

    @JsonField
    public String url;

    @JsonField
    public String description;
}
```

e depois que você tiver feito a consulta e tiver o JSON em sua variável basta chamar o LoganSquare.

```
SeuObjeto obj = LoganSquare.parse(strJSON, SeuObjeto.class);
```

Espero ter ajudado..

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta, mas como é para efeitos académicos gostava de usar bibliotecas nativas, contudo senão conseguir irei com certeza consultar... E claro tem o meu +1 pela disponibilidade...